# Discretized Brownian motion: convergence of two different versions

Tags: taylor-expansion, stochastic-calculus

We know the most popular function of the geometric Brownian motion

$$
\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t
$$

We can write the geometric Brownian motion as the discretized version

$$
\frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{S_{n-1}} = \mu\Delta + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta} Z_n
$$

If we have a fixed time $T > 0$, divide $[0,T]$ into $N$ equal segments, $\Delta = \frac{T}{N}$.
Moreover, based on the solution of geometric Brownian motion, we can write in another form such that $\nu = \mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}$,

$$
S_n = S_{n-1}e^{\nu\Delta + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta} Z_n}
$$

Could someone provide proof of why these two functions are equivalent when $\Delta$ tends to zero? Thank you very much.